# Stripping out the time component from xsd:date

Tags: date, service, web, xsd

I am building the server side of a web service using Apache Axis. The service performs some logic and returns a date to the caller. The requirement is that the returned date should be in the format YYYY-MM-DD. (say 2013-07-01). There should NOT be any time component in the value.

I ran the WSDL through wsdl2java tool. This generated the Skeleton and input/output parameter java classes. I used ADB for binding. I see that for types that were defined as xsd:date in the XSD, the corresponding generated java data type is java.util.Date.

In the service logic, I populated the date field with a java.util.Date in code. I see that the web service response includes the time component as well. Something like:

2013-07-10-04:00
2014-06-30-04:00

I do not want the :00 in the value. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this link about how to use an xml adapter](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/exchanging_data_with_xml_and)

You can use an adapter in your jaxb definition to define how you want the date to be returned. You would also need to point at this adapter in your xsd:date definition.
Use [@XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.1.3/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html)

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    // the desired format
    private String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";

    public String marshal(Date date) throws Exception {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(date);
    }

    public Date unmarshal(String dateString) throws Exception {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(dateString);
    }
```